# Is there any way to find the currently visible tabs in horizontalScrollVIew?

Tags: android

I have implemented a HorizontalScrollView in my TabWidgets to scroll tabs.How do i know which 
tabs are currently visible when user scroll the tabs?

Is there any way to find the currently visible tabs?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

It's quite difficult while there is no "tabls" in scroll views.

Comment: actually i have implemented an arrow both side of the tabs.so i will make left arrow and right arrow visible/invisible according to the visible tabs.

Comment: i am trying from last two days but i fail.so if you could help to solve this problem?

Comment: If you implemented buttons, it means you know what tab you displaying?

Answer (score 0):

if you know the width of each tab (i'm assuming they are all same). you will know the starting  and ending locations of each view.

using

```
HorizontalScrollView.getScrollX();
```

you will be able to calculate if a view is visible or not. since you will know the start and end points of horizontal scroll view as well.

based on your comment.

there is

```
HorizontalScrollView.getLeft()
HorizontalScrollView.getRight()
```

you can use them to find if the scroll view is full left or full right to toggle the arrows.

there is also an

```
hsv.getMaxScrollAmount()
```

which should be used to find the right end and the left should be 0 i guess.

**UPDATE**

i found this today.

```
View.willNotDraw()
```

your buttons in side the horizontal scroll  view should have this method. check, if this helps. i guess this will tell if a view gets drawn or not.

Comment: currently i am trying the same thing. it works quite good but still some problem arise when i scroll tabs differently.

Comment: No it's not working .is there any way to find the direction of scrolling.

Comment: i guess you can extend the HorizontalScrollView to make your customHScroll and may be insert some flags in methods like getRightFadingEdgeStrength() and onOverScrolled() to get your job done

Comment: @Pankit Mistry: i have updated my response, as i found a new method.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem for me. Try implementing this at your PagerAdapter

```
class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
                      ...

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {          

        // This makes the TabHost scroll to certain x position 
        // determined by scrollPos
        View tabView = mTabHost.getChildAt(position);
        final int scrollPos = (int) (mTabHost.getWidth() * (position / (double) Math.pow(getCount(),2)));
        hScrollView.smoothScrollTo(scrollPos, 0);
    }
                             ...
}
```

Even if it worked for me the values for the scroll may be wrong. Hope it helps :)